# Angular angular-font-awesome not displaying font

Tags: angular5

I am new to Angular. I tried to add the angular-font-awesome module as described.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-font-awesome

But it is not displaying the icon. If I use the cdn in my index the icons display perfectly fine (but I gues that's not the way to go..). I am using scss, so i changed this in the cli: (My styles.scss styles display also fine)
I also tried the path ../node_modules - not working.

```
 "styles": [
        "sass/styles.scss",
        "./node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss"
      ],
```

import { AngularFontAwesomeModule } from 'angular-font-awesome';

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AppNavbarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFontAwesomeModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }


<a class="icon"><fa name="cog"></fa></a>
```

Comment: Should it be "../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss" ?? two dots in front of the slash?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a direct `css` link in `index.html`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52940958/249097) post for additional details.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Question is why it doesn't work by providing link in angular.json? In my case bootstrap works fine. Only for font awesome I have to add link into index.html to work icons properly.

Source:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reciptor?file=src%2Findex.html