# Font awesome icons not showing up in Angular 5

Tags: angular, font-awesome, angular5

I installed it according to the instructions. First I've typed

`npm install --save font-awesome angular-font-awesome`

And it installed everything correctly. Then I changed in `.angular-cli.json` to contain the css like so:

```
 "styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"
  ],
```

And when I type this in the html: `<span class="fas fa-chevron-left"></span>`

It does not show anything at all for it.

I don't have errors either but in sources I can't find anything related to font awesome.

Comment: `<span class="fa fa-chevron-left"></span>`

Comment: Didn't work for me

Comment: `"../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css`

Comment: Also doesn't work. I also checked if the location exists and it does.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in browser console.

Comment: it should be work. try `npm install` and run again `ng s -o`

Comment: alter solution: leave it and use cdn in index file. https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

Comment: Sorry for the stupid mistake I think it was because I didn't restart the server using `ng s -o`. After I did that it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
```

Use this it will help you

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the correct fix, but i had to use this in `index.html` to get the icons working.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
```

According to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-font-awesome) in `npm`, the above link is needed only if you are NOT using `angular-cli`